# Cocos2d works on simulator, but not device

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My question is that when I try to use

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grass.png"];
```

It crashes but doesn't say why. I've checked my image and its included in the copy bundle resources. Help.

Comment: really absolutely nothing printed in the log?

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for what you are experiencing is related to the iOS filesystem being case sensitive, whereas the OS X is not. So, double check that the file is not actually called "Grass.png" or other variations thereof.